# installed full xcode on mavericks macbook, but homebrew install says command line tools not installed

Tags: xcode, homebrew

Installed the full XCODE (about 2 GB) in a brand new mavericks macbook, using App Store, then rebooted. Ran Xcode. Went to Preferences > Location, verified Command Line Tools shows up (v 5.0.2 5A3005).

In terminal, `xcode-select -print-path` shows `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer` plus I can now run `gcc --version` and see version info.

So AFAIK command line tools are installed.

However, when I try to install homebrew, it opens the gui dialog offering to install XCode or the command line tools.

I don't want to end up double-installing, with conflicting paths, so any help on why the brew installer isn't "seeing" the commandline tools would be appreciated.

Comment: looks like might be a homebrew issue that it's not able to find the command line tools 'inside' Xcode... see these two issuesL https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/issues/24471 and https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/issues/20427

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted in my comment, it is in fact a homebrew issue that it's not able to find the command line tools 'inside' Xcode due to Xcode recently changing where the command line tools were located... see these two issuesL github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/issues/24471 and github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/issues/20427

The solution was therefore to simply accept the option to install the command line tools when the gui window pops up after homebrew can't find them.